# Bucketing Verbs into categories- Is there an alternative to NLTK's Verbnet?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to identify verbs which help in specifying the usage of an application.

Examples of such verbs: *Update , Process , integrate , forecast.*

I want to check the presence of such verbs in descriptions of Applications like:

- MS Excel is used to **prepare** tables and **forecast** profits VS
- Code is used to **write** python

Had initially planned to use [NLTK Verbnet](https://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#verbnet-corpus-reader) to categorize verbs by using `verbnet.classids(verb)`, but have realized that it does not have verbs like *download, update , process etc*. Hence I am asking for recommendations of alternatives to verbnet that has a larger corpus of verbs and can categorize them.

Please let me know if I should post this question to another forum. Have posted it here because I want this to be a solution in python and am currently using a Python library - NLTK

Adding few examples of how Verbnet helps to classify verbs into categories:

```
#import
from nltk.corpus import verbnet

#use verbnet to list categories of verbs
print("categories for 'write'","-->",verbnet.classids("write"))
print()
print("categories for 'bake'","-->",verbnet.classids("bake"))
```

Results:

```
categories for 'write' --> ['lecture-37.11-1', 'performance-26.7-2-1', 'scribble-25.2', 'transfer_mesg-37.1.1-1-1']

categories for 'bake' --> ['build-26.1', 'cooking-45.3', 'preparing-26.3-1']
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your task is? Is it that you have a fixed vocabulary of words you care about e.g. _process_, _integrate_, _forecast_, ... and you want to detect occurrences of any of those words in some input text?

Comment: @Luke G My task is to check for the existence of verbs like `prepare , use , forecast , update` in a dataset that has 1 million Application Descriptions (applications like MS Excel , VS Code , Chrome etc) .. I am doing this check to identify if the Application's description actually specify how the application is used..  Given it's a huge dataset , I don't have a fixed set of verbs I am searching for.. Hence I want to identify verbs that fall into a category - A category which can be used with Applications... So I don't want verbs like eat or play as an application can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can spacy language model,

```
 import spacy
 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

 data = ['I am to update my resume', 'I want to process huge dataset in python',
   'I want integrate my development code to my production code',
   'The company is forecasting reduced profits']

for text in data:
    doc = nlp(text)
    print("<-----Text------->")
    for token in doc:
        print(token,"-->", token.pos_)

#op
<-----Text------->
I --> PRON
am --> AUX
to --> PART
update --> VERB
my --> PRON
resume --> NOUN
<-----Text------->
I --> PRON
want --> VERB
to --> PART
process --> VERB
huge --> ADJ
dataset --> NOUN
in --> ADP
python --> PROPN
<-----Text------->
I --> PRON
want --> VERB
integrate --> VERB
my --> PRON
development --> NOUN
code --> NOUN
to --> ADP
my --> PRON
production --> NOUN
code --> NOUN
<-----Text------->
The --> DET
company --> NOUN
is --> AUX
forecasting --> VERB
reduced --> VERB
profits --> NOUN
```

But again , this is language model you need to check which one is working fine for your dataset.
To achieve 100 % accuracy for your problem statement will be difficult

Comment: I have indeed used spacy to identify verbs. My question is about how would one categorize verbs into different categories assuming verbs have already been identified... :). I have updated my question's description  and added a comment on the question to elaborate further.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630194/extract-top-n-words-that-are-most-similar-to-an-input-word-from-a-text-file you can use approach finding similar word from your data ...